# Algorithm for optimal 2D color palette arrangement

Tags: algorithm, optimization, colors

Given a set of *256* colors I wish to create a *16 x 16 palette* from these colors where the sum of all 4-connected differences between colors in minimal. Of course there are 256! different arrangements so brute force is not considered.

I tried using a greedy algorithm where I start with the color closest to black and proceed in a zig-zig diagonal fashion through the 16x16 grid inserting the closest unused color to the already inserted one or two neighbors. The following (crummy) palette was the result:

[image]

I used perceptual [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) with a [low-cost approximation using RGB](https://www.compuphase.com/cmetric.htm). Of course the algorithm should be the same regardless of the difference metric.

I assume the optimal solution is (at least) NP-hard (I am not sure how a NP verifier would work so maybe this problem isn't even in NP). If not, let me know. Otherwise, good heuristic solutions are acceptable.

Comment: You are trying to find the "best" permutation of the colors, based on your distance metric.  There are lots of ways to tackle that; genetic algorithms & simulated annealing come first to mind.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking some randomized heuristic method like simulated annealing or belief propagation... I guess I was hoping that maybe there is a clever algorithm in P that I am not seeing.

Comment: Maybe for certain difference metrics, but in general, not unless P=NP.

Comment: The dark patch in the middle seem like a bug in the implementation. And the two red pixels in the bottom right just seem like left-overs, which is to be expected with a greedy algorithm. Other than that, you seem to have achieved the stated goal: *"the 4-connected difference between colors in minimal."*

Comment: @user3386109 -- this clearly not optimal.

Comment: This comment was going to suggest that the goal needs to be changed. But apparently you've found another avenue of research, so best of of luck.

Comment: You describe the metric for comparing two individual colours, but now these are aggregated: Do you want to minimise, e.g., the sum of these differences over all neighbouring pixel pairs?  The maximum of these differences?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I wish to minimize the sum of differences between all 4-connected pairs (Thanks -- I'll edit the description).

Comment: You're welcome :) Unfortunately it's very likely that the general n\*m form of this problem is already NP-hard for m=1, since if we consider the slight variation in which the scoring function also penalises the "wraparound edge" from the rightmost to the leftmost colour, then there would be a straightforward reduction from Euclidean TSP (you could make a colour for each city with, say, R and G components set to its x and y positions, respectively, and B set to 0).  I can't think of a reduction for the original variant though (in which we don't care about this wraparound edge)...

Comment: I think your greedy algorithm is probably doing pretty well, but you can probably do better by using beam search instead.

Comment: Yeah I think this is called the *k-dimensional (Grid) Arrangement Problem*(k_GAP) with the case k = 2. The problem is hard even for the k = 1 case.

Comment: @wcochran Can you explain what is 4-connected pairs?

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya Regular 2D grid points are usually considered to be either 4-connected or 8-connected. 4-connected means each point is connected with its north, east, west, and south neighbors; 8-connected also includes diagonals NE, SE, SW, NW. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity